# How to import an existing single site into an existing drupal 7 multisite

Tags: 7, multi-sites

What would be the steps to take to add an existing site into an existing multisite that already has several sites in it.
The existing multi site is on acquia cloud and the single site that I want to add to it is on my local computer .

Thanks